# How do I create a bot in Xcode? Getting "Creating a bot requires a project that is under source control."

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcode5, osx-mavericks, osx-server

I'm trying to get Continuous Integration setup in Mavericks using OS X Server for Mavericks.

I have the Server installed and my source code is in a local directory using Git from assembla. I'm following the Apple Xcode Continuous Integration Guide, and I'm at the part where I'm adding a bot to the product in Xcode.

I'm getting the error:

> Creating a bot requires a project that is under source control. This project appears to be in a local git repository. To be able to create a bot, the project must be in an repository the server can access so it can clone it. [cancel] [Configure Remotes...]

Clicking either cancel or configure remotes brings up the configure for my folder and I see my remote added just fine. I also tried adding the remote repository again with a different name.

How do I move forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this issue happens when there isn't a remote named "origin", as that's what Xcode is looking for. When I renamed my remote to origin (in `<ProjectRoot>/.git/config`), Xcode stopped complaining and let me add a bot through the Xcode UI.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is hacky, but worked.

In Xcode I clicked the Source Control menu then checkout. I checked out my repository to a new folder and I was able to create my bot.

It seems adding the repository from the command line caused things to not look correctly configured to Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

After numerous trials I did the following steps to get the whole process to work:

1. Connect a device to the server. Make sure it is active.
2. Set up the server and ensure that the XCode service is active.
3. Create a new project with a local GIT.
4. In the `Source Control` menu, select `Configure`, and under `Remotes` select to `Create New Remote`.
5. Go to `Manage Schemes` and check the `Shared` check box.
6. Commit the project and select `Push` to master.
7. Go to the developer site and create an developer and Ad-Hoc profile.
8. Go to the Xcode settings and reload the profiles for the team / developer.
9. Configure this profile in the app build settings.
10. Select to create a bot with CI to run on commit.

The next time you commit this should run the bot etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to edit a bot that I created before. In my case the problem was that I created the bot for the master branch, but when I tried to edit it, I had checked out a different branch. After switching back to master I was able to successfully edit my bots.

Answer (score 1):

Tried most of the things here. None worked for me. Got this error

> Creating a bot requires a project that is under source control..

But when I proceeded with the popup it said

> All projects are in workspace (something similar).

I did the below

- Removed .git folder
- git init
- git remote add origin <repo.git>
- git pull origin <branch_name>
- removed the conflicting folders and files
- git pull origin <branch_name>

Then when I clicked create bot from Products it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the easiest time of all. I simply did an Xcode-based commit and push, then tried the bot again, and the nasty error was gone.

[In Xcode 6.4, this would crash the Xcode].