# Being asked for Repository Credentials when creating a Bot on Xcode 5 Mavericks Server

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to set up `continuous integration`. I've a Mac. I work from and a Mac Server with all the Xcode server stuff set up on it. When I try and create a `bot` from my work Mac, I get to a screen titled-

```
Provide repository credentials for this host.
```

It has three repos listed. Trouble is, there should be only one repo. The server has the one repo set up on it, and it's the one I'm working from on my work Mac. But the repository credentials screen asks me for the credentials for this repo (which come up with a green checkmark), one repo that used to be a sub-module of this repo, and one repo that I don't believe was ever connected to this repo.

My repo has no sub-modules (although it used to). Where are these other two repos coming from in the list? I'm using Git.

Is it possible they're lingering around somewhere in the repo settings?

Comment: How did you check out the repository? It looks like that might make a difference. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19628675/1085891

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not checking out `master` by mistake or other branch that may not be the one you intended. This may make the Xcode bot download a version of your repo that still points to those submodules.

Also, ever since Xcode 5, there is a new file with the `xccheckout` extension. It is in:

```
< Your Project >.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/< Your Project >.xccheckout
```

Make sure you didn't add this file to `.gitignore` some time ago. It looks like Xcode bots use this file to look at submodules and if it was ignored in the past it has an incorrect state, possibly still mentioning your older git submodules.